# XML Charset Conversion Tool

Tags: xml, utf-8, character-encoding

i have a bunch of xml-files (like several hundret) in the iso-8859-1 encoding, and want to convert them to utf-8. SO i need a tool that will convert the characters and also replace the xml header, which is  right now. When they get interpreted as UTF-8, all the special characters like ö,ä,ü etc. are broken. Ideally it would also validate and fix the indenting. There are several tools i found online for converting between encodings, but i need one for xml that also replaces the header and is capable of doing that for all xml files in the folder and subfolders, ideally while ignoring other files. It should also preferrably be free. Does anyone know such a tool?

Comment: A single XSLT will do the job, i.e.XML  prolog, encoding, and indenting.

Comment: If i understood that correctly, that way it would be hard to make it so that it actually replaces it in all files in a folder?

Comment: Just a batch file that will loop through a directory and apply a single generic XSLT (an identity transformation) to all XML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generic so called identity transformation XSLT.
All `<xsl:output` tag attributes will do exactly what you need.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So i must use a batch script to call e.g. msxsl.exe for all the xml files, correct?

Comment: ok... seems to be half way to what i want. I just struggle to get msxsl.exe overwrite the input file. Is that actually not possible?

Comment: It is better to create a copy of the original XML file(s).